# Как сделать анимированный поиск?

Tags: html, jquery, css

[image: Пример]

Как корректно сделать выезжающий поиск при нажатии на иконку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как один из вариантов:

```js
$('.search__label').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  var $this = $(this),
      form = $this.closest('.search__form'),
      input = form.find('.search__input');
  
  input.toggleClass('show');
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
  var container = $('.search__input');
  if (container.has(e.target).length === 0 && 
      $(e.target).closest('form').length === 0){
    container.removeClass('show');
  }
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border: box;
}

.search__form {
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;  
}

.search__label {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 0;
}

.search__input {
  width: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 35px;
  height: 30px;
  
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.search__input.show {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  
<form class="search__form">
  <input type="search" name="search" id="search" class="search__input" placeholder="Search">
  <label for="search" class="search__label"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>
</form>
```

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы поиск закрывался, если нажать на области вне поиска?

Comment: @SergeyEremin, обновила ответ, посмотрите

Comment: Сейчас к сожалению, при нажатии внутри окна поиска, поиск закрывается.

Comment: проверяйте сейчас

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, направление как сделать так, чтобы скрытый блок не имел ширину 300px (так как этот блок перекрывает другие элементы). А ширина увеличивалась при активации поиска. То есть область поиска в неактивном состоянии имеет ширину иконки, а когда нажимаешь её, то выезжает поиск в том числе и его родительский блок.

Comment: @SergeyEremin, задайте это отдельным вопросом

Comment: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/658185/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%83) Буду признателен любой помощи или совету как добавить нужные действия.