# Как сделать раскрывающиеся поиск при нажатии на иконку?

Tags: jquery, css

[image: Пример]

Как сделать анимированный поиск, раскрывающиеся после нажатия на иконку?

В коде jquery вижу нужный сценарий для мобильной версии. Единственно нужно корректно убрать проверку ширины экрана и сделать поиск с иконкой по умолчанию. Помогите, пожалуйста, внести изменения корректно. К сожалению опыта не хватает.

[Пример того, что есть сейчас](http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/)

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/*jshint browser:true jquery:true*/
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/template',
    "matchMedia",
    'jquery/ui',
    'mage/translate'
], function ($, _, mageTemplate, mediaCheck) {
    'use strict';

    /**
     * Check wether the incoming string is not empty or if doesn't consist of spaces.
     *
     * @param {String} value - Value to check.
     * @returns {Boolean}
     */
    function isEmpty(value) {
        return (value.length === 0) || (value == null) || /^\s+$/.test(value);
    }

    $.widget('mage.quickSearch', {
        options: {
            autocomplete: 'off',
            minSearchLength: 2,
            responseFieldElements: 'ul li',
            selectClass: 'selected',
            template:
                '<li class="<%- data.row_class %>" id="qs-option-<%- data.index %>" role="option">' +
                    '<span class="qs-option-name">' +
                       ' <%- data.title %>' +
                    '</span>' +
                    '<span aria-hidden="true" class="amount">' +
                        '<%- data.num_results %>' +
                    '</span>' +
                '</li>',
            submitBtn: 'button[type="submit"]',
            searchLabel: '[data-role=minisearch-label]',
            isExpandable: null
        },

        _create: function () {
            this.responseList = {
                indexList: null,
                selected: null
            };
            this.autoComplete = $(this.options.destinationSelector);
            this.searchForm = $(this.options.formSelector);
            this.submitBtn = this.searchForm.find(this.options.submitBtn)[0];
            this.searchLabel = $(this.options.searchLabel);
            this.isExpandable = this.options.isExpandable;

            _.bindAll(this, '_onKeyDown', '_onPropertyChange', '_onSubmit');

            this.submitBtn.disabled = true;

            this.element.attr('autocomplete', this.options.autocomplete);

            mediaCheck({
                media: '(max-width: 768px)',
                entry: function () {
                    this.isExpandable = true;
                }.bind(this),
                exit: function () {
                    this.isExpandable = false;
                    this.element.removeAttr('aria-expanded');
                }.bind(this)
            });

            this.searchLabel.on('click', function (e) {
                // allow input to lose its' focus when clicking on label
                if (this.isExpandable && this.isActive()) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }.bind(this));

            this.element.on('blur', $.proxy(function () {

                setTimeout($.proxy(function () {
                    if (this.autoComplete.is(':hidden')) {
                        this.setActiveState(false);
                    }
                    this.autoComplete.hide();
                    this._updateAriaHasPopup(false);
                }, this), 250);
            }, this));

            this.element.trigger('blur');

            this.element.on('focus', this.setActiveState.bind(this, true));
            this.element.on('keydown', this._onKeyDown);
            this.element.on('input propertychange', this._onPropertyChange);

            this.searchForm.on('submit', $.proxy(function() {
                this._onSubmit();
                this._updateAriaHasPopup(false);
            }, this));
        },

        /**
         * Checks if search field is active.
         *
         * @returns {Boolean}
         */
        isActive: function () {
            return this.searchLabel.hasClass('active');
        },

        /**
         * Sets state of the search field to provided value.
         *
         * @param {Boolean} isActive
         */
        setActiveState: function (isActive) {
            this.searchLabel.toggleClass('active', isActive);

            if (this.isExpandable) {
                this.element.attr('aria-expanded', isActive);
            }
        },

        /**
         * @private
         * @return {Element} The first element in the suggestion list.
         */
        _getFirstVisibleElement: function () {
            return this.responseList.indexList ? this.responseList.indexList.first() : false;
        },

        /**
         * @private
         * @return {Element} The last element in the suggestion list.
         */
        _getLastElement: function () {
            return this.responseList.indexList ? this.responseList.indexList.last() : false;
        },

        /**
         * @private
         * @param {Boolean} show Set attribute aria-haspopup to "true/false" for element.
         */
        _updateAriaHasPopup: function(show) {
            if (show) {
                this.element.attr('aria-haspopup', 'true');
            } else {
                this.element.attr('aria-haspopup', 'false');
            }
        },

        /**
         * Clears the item selected from the suggestion list and resets the suggestion list.
         * @private
         * @param {Boolean} all - Controls whether to clear the suggestion list.
         */
        _resetResponseList: function (all) {
            this.responseList.selected = null;

            if (all === true) {
                this.responseList.indexList = null;
            }
        },

        /**
         * Executes when the search box is submitted. Sets the search input field to the
         * value of the selected item.
         * @private
         * @param {Event} e - The submit event
         */
        _onSubmit: function (e) {
            var value = this.element.val();

            if (isEmpty(value)) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }

            if (this.responseList.selected) {
                this.element.val(this.responseList.selected.find('.qs-option-name').text());
            }
        },

        /**
         * Executes when keys are pressed in the search input field. Performs specific actions
         * depending on which keys are pressed.
         * @private
         * @param {Event} e - The key down event
         * @return {Boolean} Default return type for any unhandled keys
         */
        _onKeyDown: function (e) {
            var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

            switch (keyCode) {
                case $.ui.keyCode.HOME:
                    this._getFirstVisibleElement().addClass(this.options.selectClass);
                    this.responseList.selected = this._getFirstVisibleElement();
                    break;
                case $.ui.keyCode.END:
                    this._getLastElement().addClass(this.options.selectClass);
                    this.responseList.selected = this._getLastElement();
                    break;
                case $.ui.keyCode.ESCAPE:
                    this._resetResponseList(true);
                    this.autoComplete.hide();
                    break;
                case $.ui.keyCode.ENTER:
                    this.searchForm.trigger('submit');
                    break;
                case $.ui.keyCode.DOWN:
                    if (this.responseList.indexList) {
                        if (!this.responseList.selected) {
                            this._getFirstVisibleElement().addClass(this.options.selectClass);
                            this.responseList.selected = this._getFirstVisibleElement();
                        }
                        else if (!this._getLastElement().hasClass(this.options.selectClass)) {
                            this.responseList.selected = this.responseList.selected.removeClass(this.options.selectClass).next().addClass(this.options.selectClass);
                        } else {
                            this.responseList.selected.removeClass(this.options.selectClass);
                            this._getFirstVisibleElement().addClass(this.options.selectClass);
                            this.responseList.selected = this._getFirstVisibleElement();
                        }
                        this.element.val(this.responseList.selected.find('.qs-option-name').text());
                        this.element.attr('aria-activedescendant', this.responseList.selected.attr('id'));
                    }
                    break;
                case $.ui.keyCode.UP:
                    if (this.responseList.indexList !== null) {
                        if (!this._getFirstVisibleElement().hasClass(this.options.selectClass)) {
                            this.responseList.selected = this.responseList.selected.removeClass(this.options.selectClass).prev().addClass(this.options.selectClass);

                        } else {
                            this.responseList.selected.removeClass(this.options.selectClass);
                            this._getLastElement().addClass(this.options.selectClass);
                            this.responseList.selected = this._getLastElement();
                        }
                        this.element.val(this.responseList.selected.find('.qs-option-name').text());
                        this.element.attr('aria-activedescendant', this.responseList.selected.attr('id'));
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        },

        /**
         * Executes when the value of the search input field changes. Executes a GET request
         * to populate a suggestion list based on entered text. Handles click (select), hover,
         * and mouseout events on the populated suggestion list dropdown.
         * @private
         */
        _onPropertyChange: function () {
            var searchField = this.element,
                clonePosition = {
                    position: 'absolute',
                    // Removed to fix display issues
                    // left: searchField.offset().left,
                    // top: searchField.offset().top + searchField.outerHeight(),
                    width: searchField.outerWidth()
                },
                source = this.options.template,
                template = mageTemplate(source),
                dropdown = $('<ul role="listbox"></ul>'),
                value = this.element.val();

            this.submitBtn.disabled = isEmpty(value);

            if (value.length >= parseInt(this.options.minSearchLength, 10)) {
                $.get(this.options.url, {q: value}, $.proxy(function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
                        element.index = index;
                        var html = template({
                            data: element
                        });
                        dropdown.append(html);
                    });
                    this.responseList.indexList = this.autoComplete.html(dropdown)
                        .css(clonePosition)
                        .show()
                        .find(this.options.responseFieldElements + ':visible');

                    this._resetResponseList(false);
                    this.element.removeAttr('aria-activedescendant');

                    if (this.responseList.indexList.length) {
                        this._updateAriaHasPopup(true);
                    } else {
                        this._updateAriaHasPopup(false);
                    }

                    this.responseList.indexList
                        .on('click', function (e) {
                            this.responseList.selected = $(e.currentTarget);
                            this.searchForm.trigger('submit');
                        }.bind(this))
                        .on('mouseenter mouseleave', function (e) {
                            this.responseList.indexList.removeClass(this.options.selectClass);
                            $(e.target).addClass(this.options.selectClass);
                            this.responseList.selected = $(e.target);
                            this.element.attr('aria-activedescendant', $(e.target).attr('id'));
                        }.bind(this))
                        .on('mouseout', function (e) {
                            if (!this._getLastElement() && this._getLastElement().hasClass(this.options.selectClass)) {
                                $(e.target).removeClass(this.options.selectClass);
                                this._resetResponseList(false);
                            }
                        }.bind(this));
                }, this));
            } else {
                this._resetResponseList(true);
                this.autoComplete.hide();
                this._updateAriaHasPopup(false);
                this.element.removeAttr('aria-activedescendant');
            }
        }
    });

    return $.mage.quickSearch;
});
```

Comment: лучше замените php код на какой у вас выходит в конце в html, а то так неудобно смотреть.

Answer (score 2):

Тут есть некоторые мелочи, которые можно допилить, но в базовом варианте это может выглядеть так:

```js
//* обработка клика по кнопке
$('body').on('click', 'button', function(e) {
  if ($('#search').val() == '' ||  !$('.field').hasClass('opened')) {
    //* если текстовое поле пустое или свернуто - не даем форме отправиться
    //* и сворачиваем/разворачиваем его
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.field').toggleClass('opened');
  }
});
//* не даем свернуться текстовому полю при клике на нём
$('body').on('click', '.field', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
//* сворачиваем поле при кли клике в любом месте
$('html').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.field').removeClass('opened');
});
```

```css
form {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
}

.actions {
  float: right;
  width: 10%;
}

.field.search {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.field.search.opened {
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  transition: all 300ms ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block block-content">
        <form class="form minisearch" id="search_mini_form" action="http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/catalogsearch/result/" method="get">
            <div class="actions">
                <button type="submit" title="Search" class="action search">
                    <span>Search</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="field search">
                <label class="label" for="search" data-role="minisearch-label">
                    <span>Search</span>
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input id="search" type="text" name="q" value="" placeholder="Search entire store here..." class="input-text" maxlength="128" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="false" aria-autocomplete="both" autocomplete="off">
                    <div id="search_autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete" style="display: none;"></div>
                    <div class="nested">
    <a class="action advanced" href="http://magento2-demo.nexcess.net/catalogsearch/advanced/" data-action="advanced-search">
        Advanced Search    </a>
</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Без вашего конфликтующего кода трудно что-то сказать

Comment: Благодарю! Код добавил. Вижу в нём уже есть нужные сценарии, только получается, что проверка ширины экрана лишняя.